# Numerical solution of Fredholm Equation

Tags: numerical-integration, integral-equations

I would like to plot the solution of the Fredholm Equation
$$f\left(x\right)+\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}{1+\left(x-t\right)^2}f\left(t\right) dt=1, \ \ (|x|\leq 1)$$
I tried to use Mathematica to find a numerical solution:

```
PHI = DSolveValue[\[Phi][x] == 1 - 1/Pi*Integrate[\[Phi][t]/(1 + (x - t)^2), 
      {t, -1, 1}], \[Phi], x]
Plot[PHI, {x, -1, 1}]
```

But I obtained some errors and I can't plot the numerical solution. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: In your Latex line there is one equation and in the Mathematica code there is second one. What actually do you try to solve?

Comment: Your code works for me for the `DSolveValue` part, but you won't get a plot without assigning a value for lambda.  If you mean what you say in your code, you need to change your Latex to match.

Comment: Sorry everyone, I was wrong to copy the function in Mathematica. I corrected the post.

Comment: Are you looking for analytical solution only? This equation can be solved by numerical method like colocation or iteration.

Comment: Just to compare. The command of Maple 2021  `intsolve(f(x) + int(f(t)/(1 + (x - t)^2), t = -1 .. 1)/Pi = 1, f(x), method = collocation, order = 3)` performs $$f \! \left(x \right) =  0.09775266381 x^{2}+ 0.6581514078
 .$$ Analytical output is too long to be cited here.

Comment: @user64494 quadratic fit is an approximation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps `NestList` gives an iterated solution (Picard iteration)

```
sol = NestList[1 - 1/Pi*Integrate[#/(1 + (x - t)^2), {t, -1, 1},Assumptions -> -1 <= x <= 1] &, 0 , 10];    

Show[ Plot[sol  , {x, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}], 
Plot[sol[[-1]], {x, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Thickness[.005], Black}]]
```

[image]

This gives the  symbolic Neumann-Series  .

Comment: As we know, for some Fredholm equations the iteration method is not converge at `n->Infinity`. It has minimal error at `n` about 6. What do you think about this equation?

Comment: @ AlexTrounev How did you check the error? If I compare the difference of two succesive iterations the numerical error seems to degree monoton.

Comment: The error is the difference between the true solution and an iterative one, not between two  iterations.

Comment: @AlexTrounev But the true solution isn't known so far?

Comment: Yes it is. The true solution is known in theory only.

Answer (score 6):

You have a wonderfully behaving smooth almost flat kernel. Since you want a numerical solution, then why not simply solve it with a quadrature?

## To matrix equation with quadrature

Here's a sample code in WolframAlpha notebook:

```
n=100;
K=Table[1/(1 + (2/n*(i - j))^2), {i,n}, {j, n}];
A=N[IdentityMatrix[n]+2/n*1/Pi*K];
f=LinearSolve[A,ConstantArray[1,n]];
ListPlot[N[Table[{2/n*(i -1/2)-1,f[[i]]}, {i,n}]]]
```

[image]

Here's how it works. Convert the integral equation into a matrix equation replacing the integral with the dumbest [rectangle quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum): $$\int K(x,t) f(t)dt=\sum_{i=1}^NK(x,t_i)f(t_i)\frac 2 N$$ where $t_i=2/N*(i-1/2)-1$.

Now, after plugging the same knots into $x$ variable you get a linear system: $$f_{t_i}+\frac 2 N \sum_jK_{t_it_j}f_{t_j}=
\sum_j\left(\delta_{ij}+\frac 2 N K_{t_it_j}\right)f_{t_j}=1$$
$$\left(I+\frac 2 N K\right)f=\mathbf 1$$
which can be solved trivially with high precision as shown above.

#### Gauss-Legendre quadrature

You can go fancy by employing [Gaussian quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature). Here's an example:

```
n = 27
<< NumericalDifferentialEquationAnalysis`;
knot = 0.5
gwL = GaussianQuadratureWeights[n/3, -1, -knot];
gwC = GaussianQuadratureWeights[n/3, -knot, knot];
gwR = GaussianQuadratureWeights[n/3, knot,1];
gw = Join[gwL,gwC,gwR];
n = Length[gw]

K=Table[1/(1 + ((gw[[i,1]] -gw[[j,1]]))^2)*gw[[j,2]], {i,n}, {j, n}];
A=N[IdentityMatrix[n]+1/Pi*K];
f=LinearSolve[A,ConstantArray[1,n]];
ListPlot[N[Table[{gw[[i,1]],f[[i]]}, {i,n}]]]

f[[Floor[n/2]+1]]

Out:     0.657412
```

[image]

## Spectral decomposition

There is a different solution that gives an insight into the integral kernel. Apply the spectral decomposition to the kernel:
$$-\frac 1 \pi \frac 1 {1+(x-t)^2}=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\lambda_i \psi_i(x)\psi_i(t)$$
Once you get the eigen values $\lambda_i$ and vectors $\psi_i(x)$, the solution to your problem is:
$$f(x)\approx\sum_{i=1}^K \frac 1 {1-\lambda_i}\left(\int_{-1}^1\psi_i(t)dt\right)\psi(x)$$
, where $K$ is the number of eigenvectors used for approximation.

[image]

Usually, we order eigenvalues descending by absolute value. Because the kernel is smooth and almost flat only the first few eigenvalues are required because they decay so quickly:
[image]

The first few eigen vectors are interesting to observe. The first one gets very close to the solution:

[image]

... and clearly only odd ones are symmetric and should have nonzero values of $\int_{-1}^1\psi_i(t)dt$ integral as shown next. Also, these integrals quickly decay too, helping to cut $K$, the number of required eigen vectors for high precision approximation:

[image]
[image]
[image]

We can see now that if the right hand side wasn't simply a constant, 1 in your case, then a different - potentially larger - number $K$ of eigenvectors may have been required for a good approximation.

Here's the full code:

```
n=999;
x=N[Table[2*(i -1/2)/n-1, {i,n}]];
d=N[Table[1/(1 +(2/n* (i -j))^2)/Pi,{i,n},{j,n}]];
K = -d;
A=N[2/n*K];
{vals,v} = Eigensystem[A,11];

v1 = v[[1]]*Sum[v[[1,i]],{i,n}]/(1-vals[[1]]);
v3 = v[[3]]*Sum[v[[3,i]],{i,n}]/(1-vals[[3]]);
v5 = v[[5]]*Sum[v[[5,i]],{i,n}]/(1-vals[[5]]);
v7 = v[[7]]*Sum[v[[7,i]],{i,n}]/(1-vals[[7]]);
v9 = v[[9]]*Sum[v[[9,i]],{i,n}]/(1-vals[[9]]);
v11 = v[[11]]*Sum[v[[11,i]],{i,n}]/(1-vals[[11]]);
vapp = v1+v3+v5+v7+v9+v11;
ListPlot[Table[{x[[i]],vapp[[i]]},{i,n}]]

ListLogPlot[-vals]
ListPlot[Table[{x[[i]],v[[1,i]]}, {i,n}]]
ListPlot[Table[{x[[i]],v[[2,i]]}, {i,n}]]
ListPlot[Table[{x[[i]],v[[3,i]]}, {i,n}]]
ListPlot[Table[{x[[i]],v[[4,i]]}, {i,n}]]
```

Answer (score 5):

Long ago I borrowed the code from  [site](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com), but I don't know exactly where.

```
ClearAll["`*"]; Remove["`*"];

n = 5;
a1 = -1;
b1 = 1;
B[x_, i_] := Binomial[n, i]*((x - a1)^i*(b1 - x)^(n - i))/(b1 - a1)^n;
k[t_, x_] := -(1/(1 + (-t + x)^2));
a[x_] := 1;
f[x_] := 1;
\[Lambda] = 1/Pi;

nIntegrate[most__] := NIntegrate[most, Method -> {Automatic, SymbolicProcessing -> 0}];

K2[j_?NumericQ] := nIntegrate[B[x, j] f[x], {x, a1, b1}] // Quiet;
mid[x_?NumericQ, i_?NumericQ] := nIntegrate[\[Lambda] k[t, x] B[t, i], {t, a1, b1}] // Quiet;

K3[j_?NumericQ, i_?NumericQ] := 
nIntegrate[(a[x] B[x, i] - mid[x, i]) B[x, j], {x, a1, b1}] // Quiet;

sol = Table[Total@Table[M[i] K3[j, i], {i, 0, n}] == K2[j], {j, 0, n}];

func = Total@Table[M[i] B[x, i], {i, 0, n}] /. NSolve[sol, Table[M[i], {i, 0, n}]][[1]]

Plot[func, {x, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 1}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Some hours ago there was a tricky numerical solution at the end of your answer , why did you delete it?

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann I'm not sure it was correct.

Comment: What a pity I was hoping it would be something like the "Method of lines for  DAE systems"! What was wrong?

Answer (score 5):

One more colocation method based on Bernoulli (or Euler) polynomials with using `NMinimize` and `FindRoot`

```
 nN = 12; xcol = Table[-1 + 2 j/nN, {j, 0, nN}]; 
v[x_] := Table[BernoulliB[n, x], {n, 0, nN}]; A = Array[a, {nN + 1}]; 
u[x_] = A . v[x];
eqs = Table[
   u[xcol[[i]]] - 1 + 
    1/Pi A . 
      NIntegrate[v[t]/(1 + (xcol[[i]] - t)^2), {t, -1, 1}, 
       AccuracyGoal -> 8], {i, Length[xcol]}];
```

First method

```
sol = NMinimize[Norm[eqs], A]
```

Second method

```
sol1 = FindRoot[Table[eqs[[i]] == 0, {i, Length[eqs]}], 
  Table[{a[i], 1/10}, {i, Length[A]}]]
```

Visualization

```
Plot[{u[x] /. sol1, u[x] /. sol[[2]]}, {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: For `x=0` both methods yield `0.65741153600362792`,but using method user @Ulrich Neumann give us `2/3`.Which is correct one?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Actually `2/3=0.66666...`, and colocation method gives solution with some error of $h^2$. In my code `h=1/12`, so we have error of `1/144`.

Comment: I tried with `nN = 36` and give me: `0.6574115...` ?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Ah, I see, that your method also gives 0.657412 for `n=10`. May be  true value is not 2/3?

Comment: Looks like at `x=0` value is not `2/3`.Try: `N[Expand[DSolveValue[\[Phi][x] == 
    1 - 1/Pi*
      Integrate[\[Phi][
           t]*(Series[1/(1 + (x - t)^2), {x, 0, 4}] // Normal) // 
         Simplify // Expand, {t, -1, 1}], \[Phi][x], x]], 20]`

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk 0.657412. you can get it with high precision using my approach https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/244172/79287